# Batch script to move to another section of the script if there is no input from user

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get this script to jump to another section of the script if there is no input from the user.

Down at the if %input%== area.

What I'm trying to do is skip to the section where the script checks for .mp4 files and moves them if they are there. Am I supposed to set a variable or loop for that section? Thanks for any replies

```
@echo off
echo Checking for youtube-dl updates.

pause
youtube-dl -U
rem Enter the url or urls that you want to download from

set /p input="Enter the url(s) you want to download:"

rem Uses the youtube-dl continue (-c) option to download multiple files if not in a playlist

youtube-dl -c "%input%" 



rem pause

if %input%=="" GOTO:EOF

cls

echo Download complete, please wait while files are transfered to appropiate folder

pause

for %%o in (.mp4) do move "*%%o" "E:\Documents\scripts\videos\"
if not exist do echo .mp4 files are no longer in this directory
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following script? This script waits for 3 seconds while "file.mp4" doesn't exist. It keeps to wait until the file exists. About "filename", you can change for your script.

```
@echo off
set waittime=3
set filename=file.mp4
:loop
if not exist %filename% (
  Timeout /t %waittime% /nobreak > nul
  goto loop
)
echo Find %filename%
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing string comparison in batch you have to make sure, that both parts are equal, which in your case will never happen! In most languages strings have double quotes around them. In batch they usually do not.
To solve your problem enclose `%input%` in double quotes as well.
Note that it can be useful to do something like `"x%input%"=="x"` to prevent certain characters like `<>|`to be at the beginning of the comparison string.

You can check this on your own with these few lines:

```
@echo off
set /p input="Input something or nothing here "
echo %input%
echo "%input%"
pause
```

If you are hitting Return without any input you will see that only the bottom one will output `""` which is the string you are comparing to.